# Finding Physical page number from the virtual address of kernel BSS section

Tags: operating-system, driver, kernel-module, lynxos

I am using 32-bit x86 architecture, I have taken one global variable in kernel space, so memory for that variable will be assigned in the BSS section of kernel's virtual memory. now I have a virtual address of that global variable and using that virtual address I want to read physical page number. Is it possible to read a physical page number? If yes, How?

Can anyone please explain what are a drambase and kas_physbase?

Comment: So, which operating system you are talking about, Linux or LynxOS? They are quite different.

Comment: I am talking about LynxOs

Comment: Ok, so I removed "linux-kernel" tag.